# Understanding Chordal Graphs better

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Can someone explain what makes a graph **Chordal** in simpler terms than the wikipedia page? I don't seem to understand it really well, I read that

```
A graph is chordal if every cycle of length at least 4 has a chord.
```

Does this just mean if there is a cycle with 4 vertices, there has to be at least one chord? Does the chord have to connect within the graph (for example a Square with a chord from one corner to the other)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case phrase "cycle $C$ of simple graph $G$ has a chord" means that there is an edge $e \in E(G)$ that links two vertices of cycle $C$, but is not a part of this cycle. In other words given a cycle of length at least $4$ in chordal graph you can easily find a shorter cycle in this graph  taking a chord of the given cycle and a part of the cycle between ends of the chord. And yes, graph $K_4 - e \cong K_{1, 1, 2}$ is chordal.

P. S. You can find [several equivalent definitions](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_32.html) of chordal graphs.